# Split throwing 500 error

Tags: asp-classic, vb6

I am very new to Classic ASP and Visual Basic. I am having trouble doing a simple split. I have the following code:

```
Dim sFileName, startDate, fsObject, filObject, oArray, oSplit
oArray = Split(Replace(Request.Form("txtOutput"),vbCrLf, "|"),"|")

For Idx = 0 To Ubound(oArray)
    oSplit = Split(oArray(Idx), ",")
    response.Write(oSplit & "</br>")

Next
```

My `txtOutput` looks something like:

```
0342-John Doe,0,0,0,,
0134-Jane Doe,15,0,0,,
0343-John Smith,44.5,0,0,,
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A 500 could be anything. You need to enable full error messages.

Comment: oSplit is an array.. are you really trying to write an array followed by <br>

Comment: @VishalKumar you are correct. My `response.Write` cannot print an array, I have to loop through it. Could you modify your answer to include the contents of your comment so I can award points.

Comment: ok.. put the comment in the answer.. thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oSplit is an array.. you were trying to write an array followed by `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

Guess your code should look something like this:

```
Dim sFileName, startDate, fsObject, filObject, oArray, oSplit
oArray = Split(Replace(Request.Form("txtOutput"),vbCrLf, "|"),"|")

For Idx = 0 To Ubound(oArray)
    oSplit = Split(oArray(Idx), ",")

    For iloop=0 to ubound(oSplit)
        response.Write(oSplit(iloop) & "</br>")
    Next

Next
```

The reason of this is because you have two splits in your code, you need two counters to loop through all itens

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Dim sFileName, startDate, fsObject, filObject, oArray, oSplit
oArray = Split(Replace(Request.Form("txtOutput"),vbCrLf, "|"),"|")

If IsArray(oArray) Then
   For Idx = LBound(oArray) To Ubound(oArray)
       oSplit = Split(oArray(Idx), ",")
       If IsArray(oSplit) Then
          For Idx2 = LBound(oSplit) to uBound(oSplit)
             response.Write oSplit(Idx2) & "</br>"
          Next
       End If
   Next
End If
```

You're getting this error because you are trying to use `response.write` on an array instead of a variable.

Comment: `Split` always returns an array so the `IsArray` tests are superflous.